# Como selecionar registros diferentes entre duas tabelas

Tags: sql, mysqli

Como selecionar registros diferentes entre duas tabelas

Tentei executar a consulta com a query abaixo; mas não gerou registros;

```
SELECT
    c1.cod_coletor,
    c2.cod_coletor 
FROM item_inventarios c1
INNER JOIN funcionarios c2
ON c2.cod_coletor = c1.cod_coletor
WHERE c1.cod_coletor != c2.cod_coletor
and  c1.id_inventario='85'
```

Deixei minha consulta disponível neste link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83a9dd/1

Comment: está a ligar por uma coluna e depois está a realizar o where pelo contrário da ligação, assim não irá com certeza obter registos.

Comment: @MauroAlmeida, Minha coluna de ligação é também o valor que quero verificar a diferença. Como poderia executar da forma correta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partindo de seu SELECT original, pois não entendi as considerações feitas posteriormente, tente:

```
SELECT
    c1.cod_coletor,
    c2.cod_coletor 
FROM item_inventarios c1
FULL OUTER JOIN funcionarios c2
ON c1.cod_coletor != c2.cod_coletor
WHERE c1.id_inventario='85'
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi com o seguinte código

```
select * from item_inventarios
where cod_coletor not in (select cod_coletor
from funcionarios) and `id_inventario`='85'
```

Answer (score 0):

Não é possivel ligar as duas tabelas por uma coluna e depois colocar elas como diferente no WHERE, para isso deve-se ter outra coluna para fazer a ligação, ai sim poderia filtrar no WHERE os cod_coletor diferentes nas duas tabelas.

Coloque em alguma das duas um ID e ligue este ID na outra tabela.

Ex: Coloque na tabela funcionarios uma coluna ID e na outra tabela coloque uma colune ID_funcionarios, no select ligue as duas tabelas atraves desse ID e depois use o WHERE para retirar o que não quer, filtrando por outra coluna.

Ou então você poderia obter o registro que não está em uma das tabelas através da consulta:

```
SELECT cod_coletor FROM item_inventarios 
WHERE cod_coletor not in (SELECT funcionarios.cod_coletor FROM funcionarios) 
AND id_inventario='85'
```

Comment: Nesse caso não existe outra relação entre as duas tabelas. 
Como poderia Poderia verificar sem fazer a ligação da coluna cod_coletor?

Comment: Você poderia obter o registro que não está em uma das tabelas através da consulta:                                                                                            
                                                                      
     (SELECT c1.cod_coletor
    FROM item_inventarios c1
    WHERE c1.cod_coletor not in (SELECT funcionarios.cod_coletor FROM funcionarios)
    and  c1.id_inventario='85')

Comment: Por favor, marque minha resposta como útil caso tenha te ajudado.

Comment: @AugustoCruz Ao invés de editar a outra resposta adicionando um comentário que não é pertinente à discussão, prefira editar a sua deixando-a mais completa possível. Você alegou que o código foi copiado da sua resposta, mas ela nem código tem. Há nos comentários um trecho de código (que não pertence à resposta) que, inclusive, foi publicado depois da resposta, então não temos nem como confirmar o fato de ter sido copiado de você ou não.